Finetuning with 8.1B Llama with LORA but responses are just repetitions of the inputs on inference
I'm finetuning a Llama 8.1B using LoRA with about a 1,000 samples for 3 epochs but after training (which takes about 3 hours) the model on inference just keeps repeating the input.
I'm using the
`{
    "instruction": "Do something",
    "input": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "company": "mule inc",
    },
    "output": "Do something for John Doe at Mulesoft [{'task': 'do something for john doe', 'due_date': '2024-06-03'}, {'task': 'do something for mulesoft', 'due_date': '2024-03-15'}]."
},`

Training
`training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="./model_finetuned",
        evaluation_strategy="steps",
        #evaluation_strategy="no",
        eval_steps=100,
        save_steps=200,
        logging_dir="./logs",
        logging_steps=50,
        per_device_train_batch_size=2,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=1,  # Minimize memory requirements
        num_train_epochs=3,
        learning_rate=2e-5,
        save_total_limit=2,
        fp16=False,  # Disable FP16 for Apple Silicon
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",  # Optional: Learning rate scheduler
    )`

Inference:

`
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model.generate(
    **  inputs,
    max_new_tokens=40,
    num_beams=5,
    no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
    early_stopping=True,
    temperature=0.4,
    num_return_sequences=5,
    #top_k=50)`

But on inference output just repeats input verbatim.
Ensured correct finetuned model was being loaded. But output just repeats input for now.
Tried various configs in training and inference, beam search, greedy search and yet no luck.
